How do I load midi events from a midi file in s3 to a glue job?
In a glue job I tried the following command to load a midi file:
midi_df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options('s3a', {'paths': [midi_input_path]}, format='midi')
But I get this error
Error reading MIDI file from s3x://<path_to_midi_file>: An error occurred while calling o99.getDynamicFrame.: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "s3x"
I wonder if it's not possible to load a midi file directly into a dynamic frame in this way, and I need another approach.
I expected a dynamic frame of the midi events in the midi file.
